# How to resolve package module import error

Tags: python, nlp

I am doing some NLP processing in python and I am using the Glove library

I am trying to run this code

```
from glove import Glove, Corpus
# creating a corpus object
corpus = Corpus()
```

However, I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/malsa876/PycharmProjects/ReqPrioritization/glov.py", line 14, in <module>
    from glove import Glove, Corpus
ImportError: cannot import name 'Corpus' from 'glove' (C:\Users\malsa876\PycharmProjects\ReqPrioritization\venv\lib\site-packages\glove\__init__.py)
```

Any idea how to fix this and update the module to its latest version?the error is also replicated here:

```
https://github.com/JonathanRaiman/glove/issues/1
```

Comment: This is an open issue. While it gets Resolved, you could try the workaround suggested: run `pip3 install https://github.com/JonathanRaiman/glove/archive/master.zip`

Comment: Yes doing so has raised the ImportError: cannot import name 'Corpus' from 'glove' (C:\Users\malsa876\PycharmProjects\ReqPrioritization\venv\lib\site-packages\glove\__init__.py)

Comment: Can you try running your code in a Python interpreter and see if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Mac  validate the GCC path

In your bash file specify gcc path something like below:

`export CC=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_3/bin/gcc-9`

and execute,

`pip install glove_python`